# Jquery keydown function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get text within a span element to change depending on the key pressed using the keydown function in Jquery.

The script runs fine until it comes to all my if statements.

http://jsfiddle.net/rAhkc/1/

A sample of my script:

```
$(document).ready(pressed);
function pressed(){
    $('html').keydown(function (e) {
        var a = 65;var b = 66;var c = 67;
        if (e.keyCode == a){
            $('span').text('a');
            console.log('Key Pressed: a');
        }else if(e.keyCode == b){
            $('span').text('b');
            console.log('Key Pressed: b');
        }else if(e.keyCode == c){
            $('span').text('c');
            console.log('Key Pressed: c');
        }
    });
}
```

I have 2 different console logs that should get reported when a key is pressed. One when any key is pressed and one when a specific key gets pressed (currently only on a, b and c).

Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong and why it isn't functioning?

Comment: That particular code works for me in Chrome:  http://jsfiddle.net/MdMkv/

Comment: Your code worked fine in Chrome, IE, and FF. http://jsfiddle.net/K53Lm/ Are you on a Mac or PC? Sometimes keycodes ( like right or left ctrl ) can be different between OS. You can try using `e.which` rather than `e.keyCode`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are overwriting `e` by setting its `keycode`.

make `var ee = 69;` or something.

[**Here is a DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/dtLp8/)

Comment: Where is he setting e? He is only comparing against it. Maybe he updated since this post?

Comment: @DaveStein check the jsfiddle he posted.  He setting a var for every letter like var `q = 81;`  etc.  He refrained from posting that part here though so thats why it seems like it works.

Comment: i edited the post so that values of variables can be seen in the code

Answer (score 3):

As Rooster / FaceOfJock said, you are overwriting e, that's why not worked.

I made some changes below only to improve the understanding and make code smaller.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(pressed);
console.log('keyPressed.js is running');
function pressed(){
    console.log('pressed script began');    
    $('html').keydown(function (e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);

        var codes = {
            q:81, w:87, e:69, r:82, t:84, y:89, u:85, i:73, o:79, 
            p:80, a:65, s:83, d:68, f:70, g:71, h:72, j:74, k:75, 
            l:76, z:90, x:88, c:67, v:86, b:66, n:78, m:77, space:32, 
            backspace:8, tab:9, caps:20, enter:13, shift:16, ctrl:17, 
            alt:18
        };

        $.each(codes,function(key,code){
            if(e.keyCode == code){
                $('span').text(key);
                console.log('Key: ' + key);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're overriding the meaning of `e`. Switch the name to `evt` or something.

Also, you should use a `switch` statement instead of all of those `if`s.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        var a = 65;
        var b = 66;
        var c = 67;

        switch(e.which){
            case a:
                console.log('you pressed a')
            break;

            case b:
                console.log('you pressed b')
            break;

            case c:
                console.log('you pressed c')
            break;
        }
    })
})
```

here is the jsfiddle. run inspect element to see the results.

e.keyCode has proved troublesome for me when firing from javascript events. It is inconsistent between browsers. e.which works much better. I also thought a switch statement was more appropriate.

http://jsfiddle.net/PnjME/